# How to watch on Route changes with Nuxt and asyncData

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

Hi everybody i'm trying to watch on route changes in my nuxt js app.

Here my middleware:

```
    export default function ({ route }) {
  return route; but i don't know what to write here
}
```

index.vue File

```
  middleware: [routeReact]
```

i'm trying to write this:

```
app.context.route = route
```

but it says to me that app.context doesn't exist

Here's the point of my question i'm trying to update my data that gets from my api with axios on page if route changing
like this

this the page
[image]

i'm clicking link to next page :

[image]

but when i'm route to next page, nothing happens all data is the same:

[image]

here my asyncData code:

```
asyncData({ app }) {
return app.$axios.$get('apps/' + app.context.route.fullPath.replace(/\/categories\/?/, ''))
.then(res => {
  return {
    info: res.results,
    nextPage: res.next,
    prevPage: res.prev
    };
  })
```

}

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First thing, `context.route` or it's alias `this.$route` is immutable object and should not be assigned a value.

Instead, we should use `this.$router` and it's [methods for programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) or `<nuxt-link>` and `<router-link>`.

As I understand, you need to render the same route, but trigger `asyncData` hook in order to update component's data. Only route query is changed.

Correct way to navigate to the same page but with different data is to use link of such format:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'index', query: { start: 420 }}"
```

Then you can use nuxt provided option [watchQuery](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-watchquery) on page component and access that query inside `asyncData` as follows:

```
watchQuery: true,

asyncData ({ query, app }) {
  const { start } = query
  const queryString = start ? `?start=${start}` : ''
  return app.$axios.$get(`apps/${queryString}`)
    .then(res => {
      return {
        info: res.results,
        nextPage: res.next,
        prevPage: res.prev
      }
    })
},
```

This option does not require usage of `middleware`. If you want to stick to using middleware functions, you can add a `key` to layout or page view that is used. Here is an example of adding a `key` to default layout:

```
<nuxt :key="$route.fullPath" />
```

This will force `nuxt` to re-render the page, thus calling middlewares and hooks. It is also useful for triggering transitions when switching dynamic routes of the same page component.

Comment: upvoted! what is this queryString? does it work on both server and client

Comment: @PirateApp thanks! "queryString" in the example is a valid URL query parameter and totally depends on your application. Since route navigation occurs on the loaded page, it is reasonable to say that this functionality is relevant on the client side only. All the component lifecycle hooks will be executed if current route stays the same, but query params change (which is not happening with `watchQuery: false`)

Answer (score 0):

For Composition API (Nuxt 3 or Nuxt 2 Bridge) you can use the `watch` option on [`useAsyncData`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data#useasyncdata) / `useLazyAsyncData` / etc.

```js
const route = useRoute()
const { data: posts } = await useAsyncData(
  'posts',
  () => {},
  {
    watch: [route]
  }
)
```

In my case, on Nuxt 2 Bridge, this resulted in an infinite loop (`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`) and solved it with a workaround:

```js
const fetchSomething = () => {}

// This is a hack because `watch(route)` results in an infinite loop
const watchFlag = ref(true)
onMounted(() => {
  watchFlag.value = false
})

useLazyAsyncData('', () => {
  return fetchSomething()
})

watch(watchFlag, async () => {
  await fetchSomething()
})
```