# Watch for URL query parameter in Vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js with Vuex and I would like to trigger a mutation when somebody enters in my web with a certain parameter (ex: https://example.com/?param=abc), and pass the parameter to a state.

I tried to check the documentation of the watchQuery property https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-watchquery, but there’s no examples about how to do this, I just found this [How to watch on Route changes with Nuxt and asyncData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874435/how-to-watch-on-route-changes-with-nuxt-and-asyncdata) but I can’t see any way of how to write an action in Vuex store with watchQuery.

I tried writing:

```
actions: {
    watchQuery: true,
    asyncData ({ query, app }) {
       const { start } = query
       const queryString = start ? `?start=${start}` : ''
       return app.$axios.$get(`apps/${queryString}`)
       .then(res => {
           commit('setParam',res.data);
       })
    },
}
```

But that syntax is not allowed.

Any help would be welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding watchQuery sets a watcher for query string, meaning it's waiting for the query to **change** while the page is already rendered making it possible to call methods like `asyncData()` again.
Since you only want to save a certain parameter when the user **enters** the page and then pass the paramater to a state you just need to move your asyncData method to a page from which you want to get the parameter, you will also need to extract `store` and `query` from the context automatically passed into `asyncData` and then using the `store` and `query` save the query parameter into your state.

**Here is a simple demonstrantion**

```
// Your page from which you want to save the param
export default {
  asyncData({store, query}) { // here we extract the store and query
    store.state.somethingForSavingTheParam = query.nameOfTheParamYouWantToSave
     // instead of using store.state you could use store.commit(...) if that's what you want
  }
}
```

Comment: So following this example, entering this url in the browser `https://example.com/?nameOfTheParamYouWantToSave=abc` should save `store.state.somethingForSavingTheParam:'abc' isn't it?` Right now doing that I don't see the param saved in the store

Comment: @Joe82 That's weird, it worked for me before posting the answer and even now it works.  Do you have that asyncData function in a page? not a layout?

Comment: Right on spot, I had it in my layout page. Moved it to a page and it works perfect!

Comment: Happy it works! also if you want to use it in more pages and don't want to copy the code over and over you can have a look at [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action)